# Any MDX query within Excel vba?

Tags: vba, mdx

is there any way to execute MDX query within Excel VBA?

I thought that it can be done through [ADO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819), similarly as in SQL case (yes, I'm aware that SQL is different than MDX - issue which was mentioned many times on Stackoverflow).

 Unfortunately I can't find any examples.

- Some told about using external tools to accomplish this task, but I
  don't want to pay for them.
- Some give an examples in XMLA, but I want to execute simple MDX query
  instead

.

Comment: Did you try Google? http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2009/12/18/binding-an-excel-table-to-the-results-of-an-mdx-query/ can up pretty quickly.

Comment: https://msolap.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/returning-mdx-query-results-in-an-excel-matrix-formula/ is another method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have the following generic function that's called in VBA that based on an input MDX string, writes the data to excel. The spreadsheet does require a reference to ADO and ADOMD

```
Public Sub DisplayMDX(ipCell, ipMDX, ipExclHeadings)

    Dim sQry As String
    Dim sConnection As String
    Dim rs As ADOMD.Cellset
    Dim sServer, sDB, ts As String
    Dim hyper As Hyperlink
    Dim i, j, k, h, rowStart, colStart, dimCount As Integer
    Dim sURLLink, sCustCaption, sCustLink As String
    Dim db As ADODB.Connection

    'Open a new ADO connection
    Set db = New ADODB.Connection
    sConnection = "Provider=MSOLAP; Data Source=DW3; Initial Catalog=FDMDW1; Integrated Security=SSPI"

    db.CommandTimeout = 0
    db.Open sConnection

    'Open a CellSet to store the results of the query.
    Set rs = New Cellset

    'Tidy the query of an erroneous spaces
    sQry = Trim(ipMDX)

    'Open the query that was constructed above
    Application.StatusBar = "Getting OLAP Data"
    With rs
        .Open sQry, db
    End With

    With ActiveSheet

     'Goto cell specified
     Range(ipCell).Select

     'Find the starting point
     rowStart = ActiveCell.Row
     colStart = ActiveCell.Column
     For j = 0 To rs.Axes(1).Positions.Count - 1

        If Not ipExclHeadings Then
           dimCount = rs.Axes(1).DimensionCount
           For h = 0 To rs.Axes(1).DimensionCount - 1
                Cells(rowStart + j, colStart + h) = rs.Axes(1).Positions(j).Members(h).Caption
           Next
        End If

        For k = 0 To rs.Axes(0).Positions.Count - 1
           If Not (k = 1) Then

              If rs(k, j) <> "" Then
                 Cells(rowStart + j, colStart + dimCount + k).Value = rs(k, j)
              Else
                 Cells(rowStart + j, colStart + dimCount + k).ClearContents
              End If

           End If
           Application.StatusBar = rs(k, j)
        Next

     Next
    End With

rs.Close

Application.StatusBar = "Done"

Exit Sub
errMsg:
   MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error #" & Err.Number

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't find where you're using "ipLink" within your code. Could you describe why we need it, please?

Comment: Code crash here: Dim rs As ADOMD.Cellset (type not defined), so I added
 
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (Multi-dimensional) 2.7 Library
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.7 Library

in Tools-->References

Comment: XML for Analysis parser: The input query is not in the language specified in the Dialect property for this request.error code-2147467259

Comment: My MDX was "SELECT CUBE_NAME FROM $SYSTEM.MDSchema_Cubes where cube_source=1". It works when invoked within Analysis Services.

Comment: Sorry, I should have taken ipLink out. Yeah, you can just remove it. I was using it to embed a link in the spreadsheet.