# MDX queries using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, mdx

Is it possible to do MDX queries using VBScript?  I have successfully done SQL queries via VBScript, any idea on how to approach MDX queries?

Currently I use a connection string like the following:

```
strConn = "Driver={SQL Server};" & _
"Server=10.0.0.1;" & _
"Address=10.0.0.1,1433;" & _
"Network=DBMSSOCN;" & _
"Database=databasename;" & _
"UID=user;" & _
"PWD=password;"
```

What would I have to change it to to get it to work?

Comment: Is this useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188747/any-mdx-query-within-excel-vba

Comment: It's just using a different provider so I can't see why not, just adjust the connection string and away you go.

Comment: Definitely useful.  I am quite comfortable with VBScript and therefore it gives me a lot of freedom to get the info I need.  Currently it requires a fair amount of work via various Excel spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like the following:

```
strConn = _
    "Provider=MSOLAP.6;" & _
    "Data Source=imxxxxxx;" & _                                     '<<<name of your server here
    "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE;" & _  '<<<name of your Adv Wrks db here
    "Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

Here is an example of using it against some `mdx`:

```
Dim pubConn As ADODB.Connection
Set pubConn = New ADODB.Connection
pubConn.CommandTimeout = 0
pubConn.Open strConn

Dim cs As ADOMD.Cellset
Set cs = New ADOMD.Cellset

Dim myMdx As String
myMdx = _
  " SELECT" & _
  "  NON EMPTY" & _
  "    [Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].&[AB]&[CA] ON 0," & _
  "  NON EMPTY" & _
  "    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 1" & _
  " FROM [Adventure Works];"

cs.Open myMdx, pubConn
```

The above is from my answer (in vba) here: [VBA Reptitive MDX query to Analysis Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070692/vba-reptitive-mdx-query-to-analysis-services)

Comment: Thank you, a bit swamped right now, as soon as I can I will give it a go.